# How to show only dimensions in DevExpress pivotgrid field list?

Tags: devexpress, customization

I am using DevExpress pivotgrid for displaying data. How to show only the dimensions in the DevExpress pivotgrid FieldList/CustomizationForm, when we right click on pivot grid and select "Show field list"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to change which fields are shown in the field list?

Comment: Currently, DevExpress PivotgridFieldList/CustomizationForm popup window displays both dimensions and measures. I want to filter out the measures and display only the dimensions Or In other words, I want to hide some fields in the popup window. Is this possible?        I am using DevExpress 11.1.7 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by setting the `PivotGridField.Options.ShowInCustomizationForm` property to false.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am using DevExpress version 11.1.7. I could not see this property in pivotgridfield. I think the option "ShowInCustomizationForm" may exists in above 11.1.7. Any solution to solve this issue in 11.1.7 itself?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it exists in that version. it's not a direct property of the pivotGridFields but rather a sub-property in Options.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I set the property in the code behind. It worked for me. Thanks a bunch.